# How do I calculate the k nearest numbers to the median?

Tags: arrays, algorithm, median

I have an array of n pairwise different elements and a number k with 1<=k<=n.

Now I am **looking for an algorithm calculating the `k` numbers with the minimal absolute difference to the median of the number array**. **I need linear complexity (`O(n)`).**

**My approach:**

I find the median:

- I sort the number
- I get the middle element or if the number of elements id even then the average of the two elements in the middle and round.

After that:

- I take every number and find the absolute distance from the median. These results I save in a different array
- I sort the newly obtained array.
- I take the first k elements of the result array and I'm done.

I don't know if my solution is in `O(n)`, also whether I'm right with this idea. Can someone verify that? Can someone show me how to solve it in O(n)?

Comment: This is StackOverflow not the Code factory.... we help you when you are stuck, but you must start...

Comment: No, your sort scuppers the O(n).

Comment: Then how to solve without sorting?

Comment: If you use sorting then you have `O(nlogn)`

Comment: I have fixed the grammar in your question, I hope you do not mind.

Comment: You may be able to sort in `O(n)` using for example a radix sort. It depends (a) whether the inputs are fixed-width numbers and (b) if so, whether this is considered "cheating" even though it is technically `O(n)` in that case. `O(n)` selection is less likely to be considered "cheating" by whoever it is that invented the restriction that it must be linear, though, so the proper solution is what Boris says.

Comment: @SteveJessop I hate it when people point to RADIX sort as the ultimate solution. In the most common case, where the numbers are in the whole range of `int`, the additional constant for `RADIX` sort will be 32 (the number of bits). No way `log n` will be that much - otherwise the memory used will be really a lot. This means that the constant of RADIX sort dominates the factor when using other sorting technique.

Comment: @Boris: Sure. It's "useful" only if there's some academic requirement for an `O(n)` algorithm, because there are `O(n log n)` sorts that are faster in practice, at least for internal sorts in RAM. The practicalities of real systems (on which `n` cannot "tend to infinity") often make the academic analysis irrelevant, my comment only applies if this is an academic question.

Comment: Just take for example this array [1,4,2,6,3]. its not sorted.

Answer (score 9):

You can solve your problem like that:

You can find the median in `O(n)`, w.g. using the `O(n)` [nth_element algorithm](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/nth_element/).

You loop through all elements substutiting each with a pair: `<the absolute difference to the median>, <element's value>`. Once more you do nth_element with `n` = `k`. after applying this algorithm you are guaranteed to have the `k` smallest elements in absolute difference first in the new array. You take their indices and DONE!

Your algorithm, on the other hand uses sorting, and this makes it `O(nlogn)`.

**EDIT**: The requested example:

Let the array be `[14, 6, 7, 8, 10, 13, 21, 16, 23]`.

- After the step for finding the median it will be reordered to, say: `[8, 7, 9, 10, 13, 16, 23, 14, 21]`, notice that the array is not sorted, but still the median (13) is exactly in the middle.
- Now let's do the pair substitution that got you confused: we create a new array of pairs: `[<abs(14-13), 14>, <abs(6-13), 6>, <abs(7-13), 7>, <abs(8-13), 8>, <abs(10-13), 10>, <abs(13-13), 13>, <abs(21-13), 21>, <abs(16-13), 16>, <abs(23-13), 23>`. Thus we obtain the array: `[<1, 14>, <7, 6>, <6, 7>, <5, 8>, <3, 10>, <0, 13>, <8, 21>, <3, 16>, <10, 23>`
- If e.g. `k` is 4 we make once more nth_element(using the first element of each pair for comparisons) and obtain: `[<1, 14>, <3, 16>, <0, 13>, <3, 10>, <8, 21>, <7, 6>, <10, 23>, <6, 7>, <5, 8>]` so the numbers you search for are the second elements of the first 4 pairs: `14`, `16`, `13` and `10`

Comment: Can you show me a example? Because i can't get "the substutiting with a pair" how to do so ?

Comment: @Boris: your description says "element's index", but your worked example uses the element's value. Either is fine (if you use the index then you can look it up at the end in the original input array, assuming that the step 1 partition was done on a copy), but you probably want them to be the same. Also, if all you need at the end is the value then you can simplify a bit and do it all in place, just run nth_element using a comparator that compares the abs difference from the median.